# node.js url search/query portion is empty

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax

I am developing a website (client + server) that runs from the same machine. 
I haven't found any errors in chrome's developer tools, so I don't know where the problem is.

I try to POST a string from the client to the Node back-end, but upon performing

```
 url.parse(request.url, true).query
```

the result is empty.

Here is my client:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/newComment", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.send("val=" + commentString);
```

My commentString is "hey there"

Here is my server:

```
var path = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
else if (path == "/newComment") {

    console.log("query: " + url.parse(request.url, true).body);
    //setNewComment(comment);

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain', 
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' : '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE'
        }); // enable cors
    response.write("Recieved request");
    response.end();
}
```

And I am at the website

```
file:///C:/Users/.../website.html?name=hey+there
```

So I'd like my Node server to print out "query: hey there" but instead it prints "query undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to access the body, and this is right, yet the url doesn't hold the body's content, you should either accumulate it by listening to 'data' events:

```
let body = [];
request.on('data', (chunk) => {
            body.push(chunk);
           }).on('end', () => {
                 body = Buffer.concat(body).toString();
                 // at this point, `body` has the entire request body stored in it as a string
                               });
```

or use "express" and "body-parser".

1.Go to the request body section: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/anatomy-of-an-http-transaction/

Comment: Thank you. This worked, although I ended up using npm's parse-body